# File name matching - middle of the string

Tags: python

I have a directory with files that follow  the format: `LnLnnnnLnnn.txt`

where L = letters and n = numbers. E.g: `p2c0789c001.txt`

I would like to separate these files based on whether the second number (i.e. 0789) is odd or even.

I've only managed to get this to work if the second number ranges between 0001-0009 using the code:

```
odd_files = []
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk('.'):
   for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'p2c000[13579]*.txt'):
       odd_files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

This will return the files: `['./p2c0001c054.txt', './p2c0003c055.txt', './p2c0005c056.txt', './p2c0007c057.txt', './p2c0009c058.txt']`

Any suggestion how could I get this to work for any given four digit number?

Comment: If you know how to write `[13579]`, why can't you write `[0123456789]` instead of `0` for the other three digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to expand your wildcard to match a wider array of things.

to that end I would probably do something like:

```
for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '??????[13579]*.txt'):
```

This will match any characters before your values, it will match any of the odd values in your wildcard class and then it will accept anything to match afterwards.

This is a bit gross because as it is aaaaaaaa3alkjfdhalkjfshglkjzsdhfgs.txt would match and that is super gross. If you know that the data in the directories you are walking is well controlled that might be ok. A better solution might be to specify things a bit more. This could be done with the following expression:

```
'[a-z][0-0][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][13579][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt'
```

The fnmatch.filter method using Unix style wildcards. That means you can use the following:

? - match any single character
* - matches anything from nothing to everything
[] - this matches a class of things, use a - for a range and ! for exclusion

Answer (score 1):

Would this do it?

```
import re
regex = re.compile("[a-z][0-9][a-z]([0-9]{4})[a-z][0-9]{3}.txt")
filter(lambda x: int(regex.match(x).groups()[0]) % 2 == 1, fnmatch)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's getting a little hairy, you could always turn that into a generator and code the tests by hand:

```
def odd_files_generator():
    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk('.'):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename[6] in '13579':
                yield filename

odd_files = list(odd_files_generator)
```

If your test is growing exceedingly hard to express tersely, replace the `if filename ...` line with your explicit test code.

Answer (score 1):

There's no particular magic to constructing this kind of filter. It just
requires carefully constructing the appropriate regular expression and testing
against it. When using complex patterns with a lot of repetitive components,
errors can easily creep in. I like to define helper functions that make the
specification more human-readable and easier to modify later if need be.

```py
import re
import os

# helper functions for legible re construction
LETTER = lambda n='': '({0}{1})'.format('[A-Za-z]', n)
NUM    = lambda n='': '({0}{1})'.format('\d', n)

FILENAME = LETTER() + NUM() + LETTER() + NUM('{4}') + LETTER() + NUM('{3}') + '\.txt'
FILENAME_RE = re.compile(FILENAME)

is_odd = lambda n: int(n) % 2 > 0


def odd_nnnn(f):
    """
    Determine if the given filename `f` matches our desired LnLnnnnLnnn.txt pattern
    with the second group of numbers (nnnn) odd.
    """
    m = FILENAME_RE.search(f)
    return m is not None and is_odd(m.group(4))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Search pattern:", FILENAME

    files = ['./p2c0001c054.txt', './p2c0001c055.txt', './p2c0003c055.txt', './p2c0005c056.txt', './p2c0022c056.txt', './p2c0004c056.txt', './p2c0007c057.txt', './p2c0009c058.txt', './p2c8888c056.txt', ]
    files = [ os.path.normpath(f) for f in files ]

    root = '/users/test/whatever'

    odd_paths = [ os.path.join(root, f) for f in files if odd_nnnn(f) ]

    print odd_paths
```

The only real downside to this is that it's a little more verbose, especially compared to a hyper-compact answer like **Brad Beattie**'s.

---

[Update] It later occurred to me that a more compact way to define the regular expression might be:

```
FILENAME = "LnL(nnnn)Lnnn\.txt"

FILENAME_PAT = FILENAME.replace('L', r'[A-Za-z]').replace('n', r'\d')
FILENAME_RE = re.compile(FILENAME_PAT)
```

This more closely follows the original 'LnLnnnLnnn.txt' description. The match expression would have to change from `m.group(4)` to `m.group(1)`, because just one group is captured this way.